# OpenCV with Python specific filter not same

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a Kirsch filter in Python with OpenCV. I'm trying to do so following [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24990-retinal-blood-vessel-extraction/content/Retinal_Blood_Vessel_Extraction/VesselExtract.m).

The problem is that it gives me a totally different result than what Matlab does.

#### Expected Output

[image: Blood vessel extraction from eye]

Python and OpenCV give me an entirely black image.

Where am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I've written:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
resim = cv2.imread('filter.jpg')
resim = cv2.cvtColor(resim, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
h1 = np.array([[5, -3, -3], [-5, 0, -3], [5, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)/ 15
h2 = np.array([[-3, -3, 5], [-3, 0, 5], [-3, -3, 5]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h3 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3], [5, 0, -3], [5, 5, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h4 = np.array([[-3, 5, 5], [-3, 0, 5], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h5 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3], [-3, 0, -3], [5, 5, 5]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h6 = np.array([[5, 5, 5], [-3, 0, -3], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h7 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3], [-3, 0, 5], [-3, 5, 5]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h8 = np.array([[5, 5, -3], [5, 0, -3], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
print(h1)
new_img1 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h1)
new_img2 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h2)
new_img3 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h3)
new_img4 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h4)
new_img5 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h5)
new_img6 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h6
new_img7 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h7)
new_img8 = cv2.filter2D(resim, -1, h8)
cv2.imshow('color_image', new_img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

A mistake is in the 6th line, where you have a value of -5, instead of 5.

```
h1 = np.array([[5, -3, -3], [5, 0, -3], [5, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)/ 15
```

Comment: A bit too short to qualify as answer on SO. You should explain why and give better identification of the code fragment. As it now stays, it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the typo noticed by [golstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894979/golstar), the code doesn't use the max of all 8 of the Kirsch sub-filters. And, it doesn't threshold and invert the results.

This should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import  cv2
import  numpy

KIRSCH_K1   = numpy.array([[ 5, -3, -3], [ 5,  0, -3], [ 5, -3, -3]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K2   = numpy.array([[-3, -3,  5], [-3,  0,  5], [-3, -3,  5]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K3   = numpy.array([[-3, -3, -3], [ 5,  0, -3], [ 5,  5, -3]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K4   = numpy.array([[-3,  5,  5], [-3,  0,  5], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K5   = numpy.array([[-3, -3, -3], [-3,  0, -3], [ 5,  5,  5]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K6   = numpy.array([[ 5,  5,  5], [-3,  0, -3], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K7   = numpy.array([[-3, -3, -3], [-3,  0,  5], [-3,  5,  5]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15
KIRSCH_K8   = numpy.array([[ 5,  5, -3], [ 5,  0, -3], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=numpy.float32) / 15

def kirsch_filter(img) :
    """ Return a gray-scale image that's been Kirsch edge filtered. """
    if  img.ndim > 2 :
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    fimg    = numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K1),
              numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K2),
              numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K3),
              numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K4),
              numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K5),
              numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K6),
              numpy.maximum(cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K7),
                            cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8U, KIRSCH_K8),
                           )))))))
    return(fimg)


def threshold(img, sig = None) :
    """ Threshold a gray image in a way that usually makes sense. """
    if  img.ndim > 2 :
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    med     = numpy.median(img)
    if  sig is None :
        sig = 0.0       # note: sig can be negative. Another way: Use the %'th percentile-ish pixel.
    co      = int(min(255, max(0, (1.0 + sig) * med)))
    return(cv2.threshold(img, co, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C)[1])



if  __name__ == '__main__' :
    import  os
    import  sys

    fn      = "x.png"
    if  len(sys.argv) > 1 :
        fn  = sys.argv.pop(1)
    sig     = None
    if  len(sys.argv) > 1 :
        sig = float(sys.argv.pop(1))

    img     = cv2.imread(fn)

    kimg    = kirsch_filter(img)    # make each pixel the maximum edginess value
    timg    = threshold(kimg, sig)  # make the edges stand out
    timg    = 255 - timg            # invert the image to make the edges white

    cv2.imshow('%s kirsch filtered' % os.path.basename(fn), timg)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# eof
```

Answer (score 0):

There are serious problems in the other answers:

- They don't use float values for the calculations so some borders could be lost. See: [One Important Matter!](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html). In the next image a filter was applied directly over a CV_8U image and a CV_64F image, clearly a border is lost in the first image.

[image: Border missed by filter]

- They don't normalize the results afterwards

This implementation is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirsch_operator:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def kirsch_filter(gray):
    if gray.ndim > 2:
        raise Exception("illegal argument: input must be a single channel image (gray)")
    kernelG1 = np.array([[ 5,  5,  5],
                         [-3,  0, -3],
                         [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG2 = np.array([[ 5,  5, -3],
                         [ 5,  0, -3],
                         [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG3 = np.array([[ 5, -3, -3],
                         [ 5,  0, -3],
                         [ 5, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG4 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3],
                         [ 5,  0, -3],
                         [ 5,  5, -3]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG5 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3],
                         [-3,  0, -3],
                         [ 5,  5,  5]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG6 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3],
                         [-3,  0,  5],
                         [-3,  5,  5]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG7 = np.array([[-3, -3,  5],
                         [-3,  0,  5],
                         [-3, -3,  5]], dtype=np.float32)
    kernelG8 = np.array([[-3,  5,  5],
                         [-3,  0,  5],
                         [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)

    g1 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG1), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g2 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG2), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g3 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG3), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g4 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG4), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g5 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG5), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g6 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG6), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g7 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG7), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    g8 = cv2.normalize(cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelG8), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    magn = cv2.max(
        g1, cv2.max(
            g2, cv2.max(
                g3, cv2.max(
                    g4, cv2.max(
                        g5, cv2.max(
                            g6, cv2.max(
                                g7, g8
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    return magn
```

And these are the results applied to the sample image from Wikipedia. If you compare both results you will see that they are pretty similar:

- This implementation:
  [image: kirsch operator applied to wikipedia image]
- Results from Wikipedia in https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kirschfilter_maximum.jpg

Finally, you use this implementation like this:

```
fg = cv2.imread("Boxfilter_pavilion_original.jpg")
fg_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(fg_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)    
bin = kirsch_filter(gray)
# show results 
plt.imshow(bin, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```